# How to delete file after read in java?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have created custom processor in which read file from upstream connections and delete it when read is complete.

Here code i have try to delete file.,

```
String input_File="C:\File\Filename.txt";
File delete_Files= new File(input_File);
delete_Files.delete();
```

But i can't able to delete file in Apache Nifi only.If i have used that same in java api it could be delete file.

Can anyone please suggest me to delete file after read in Apache Nifi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your processor receives a flow file from an upstream connection by using session.get(), then you can either transfer the flow file to a relationship using session.tansfer(flowfile) and let the user decide if they want to terminate the relationship, or if you don't want to pass on the flow file then you can call session.remove(flowfile).

The data for each flow file is being stored in NiFi's internal repositories and you can only interact with the internal repositories by using the appropriate APIs on the session.